# .change function did not triggered when using javascript datepicker

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have `.change` jQuery function. All are working except for one text field. That text field will receive an input from a small pop up window which contains calendar. It is actually a datepicker. But when I click any particular calendar, it seems like the function does not detect the changes. But if I put manually the date, it is working. I try to read the jQuery documentation but cannot find the answer. Is it because of the `.change` function only triggered when we put the input using our keyboard only?

Thanks in advance guys.

my jquery codes

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".edit_tr").click(function(){

        var ID=$(this).attr('id');

        $("#first_"+ID).hide();
        $("#first_input_"+ID).show();
        var first=$("#first_input_"+ID).val();
        alert('content: '+first);

    }).change(function(){
        alert('change');
        });
  });
```

my html codes:

```
<tr id = "<?php echo $id; ?>_6" bgcolor='#f2f2f2' class='edit_tr'>
    <td><span class="pro_text-form"><font color="red">*</font> Date of Birth </span></td>
    <td class="edit_td">
    <span id="first_<?php echo $id; ?>_6" class="text"><?php echo $dob; ?></span>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $dob; ?>" class="editbox" id="hidden_first_input_<?php echo $id; ?>_6" />
    <input type="text" class="editbox" name="open_date" id="first_input_<?php echo $id; ?>_6" value="<?=$dob?>" size="10" />
    <a href="javascript:NewCal('first_input_<?php echo $id; ?>_6','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Guys, my problem solved! I have decided to change to jquery calendar, and it works really nice. just what i am looking for. but bare in mind, ensure that there is no conflict for the jquery.js. i got that problem and my calendar is not showing up. cheers.

Comment: Post your HTML and code.

Comment: are you using jquery ui?

Comment: post html code please, we could help you better!

Comment: @Muthu now I am at home, will post my codes later...

Comment: @kmb385 how to check whether we are using jquery ui or not? now i am working on a template. i can see there is a script which calls jquery 1.7.1.

Comment: @ricky hey thanks, I will put it later since now i am at home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, change is triggered on blur when the value changed. jQuery's datepicker has a similar change event you can bind to.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `onSelect` event fired by the datepicker in JqueryUI.

```
$("#myPicker").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    alert(dateText);
  }
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Comment: thanks, do I need to use the jquery calendar? because currently I am using javascript calendar....